# Laravel and timestamps - is it always a Date column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Is there a way for `Laravel` `timestamps()` to have created_at as an integer `unix timestamp`? and wouldn't this be preferable for logging many events and their times? What if the `timestamps` must have many entries, possibly to the millisecond?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's predefined. You can make a timestamp with timezone though.

- `$table->timestamps` [Adds nullable created_at and updated_at TIMESTAMP equivalent columns.](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/migrations#creating-columns)
- `$table->timestampsTz` [Adds nullable created_at and updated_at TIMESTAMP (with timezone) equivalent columns.](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/migrations#creating-columns)

Laravel casts those values to Carbon instances when you access them (using [mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators)), where you can format them however you want (including unix format).

```php
$model = Something::first();       // Random model
$model->created_at                 // Carbon instance
$model->created_at->unix()         // Unix timestamp
$model->created_at->getTimestamp() // Same, it's an alias
```

Comment: Isn't instantiating a Carbon class variable a lot slower than simply `time()`? That's what I'm wondering for performance. Not sure what the Timezone referenced is, looking up by user ip or something? That would seem to make it even slower?

Comment: In theory yes, but you won't really notice the difference. You could say instantiating a Model class is "a lot slower" than simply querying the DB. It makes sense, but unless the server is from a bygone era, you won't notice.